# Auth attempt bcrypt cause White Blank in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I have this custom login code which cause white blank.

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {    
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => bcrypt($request->password)])){          
            return Auth::check();
        }

    }
```

But if I change `'password' => bcrypt($request->password)` to `'password' => $request->password`

It successfully logged in but without querying password field. I see in laravel debug bar like this `select * from`users`where`email`= 'user@mail.com' limit 1`

`$request->email` and `$request->password` is exist, I already check it via return.

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? White screen usually means an error.

Comment: can I see your redirect page. I mean the view and it's action/routes

Comment: @Samsquanch no error log :(

Comment: @NewbeeDev no redirect function :( I just want to make sure with `Auth::check()`

Comment: I mean the laravel default redirection

Comment: @NewbeeDev thanks solved,  attempt should be use without bcrypt, and the other my problem is just about logical code.